# Heap Sort giving wrong output ( Cpp )

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

I have written the following code for Heap Sort using Max-Heap logic.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;   

void max_heapify(vector<int> &a,int i)
{

    int left=2*i+1;
    int right=2*i+2;
    if(i >= (int)a.size()/2 )
    {
        return;
    }
    int max=i;
    if(a[i]<a[left])
    {
        max=left;
    }
    if(a[max]<a[right])
    {
        max=right;
    }
    if(max!=i)
    {
        swap(a[i],a[max]);
        max_heapify(a,max);
    }    
}   

void build_maxHeap(vector<int> &a)
{
    int l=a.size();
    for(int i=l/2-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        max_heapify(a,i);
    }
}


void heap_sort(vector<int> &a)
{
    build_maxHeap(a); // max element at top.
    for(int i=a.size()-1;i>=1;i--)
    {
        swap(a[i],a[0]);
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        a.pop_back();
        max_heapify(a,0);
    }
    cout<<a[0]<<endl;       
}  

int main()
{
    vector<int> a={6,7,8,1,2,9,32};
    heap_sort(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 32 9 32 7 32 32

Expected Output: Print elements in descending order.

I don't know why there is a repetition of 32. I am popping the element from the end but can't figure out why such behavior.

Comment: your loop should be `while( a.size() > 1 ) { swap( a.front(), a.back() ); ... }` it would be much easier to read the logic

Comment: Tried. Readability sure becomes better but output still remains wrong

Comment: That was not suppose to fix your issue, otherwise I put that into answer, not comment. Anyway you need to learn how to use a debugger. I know posting to SO is easier, but sometimes people do not want to do your work - they are lazy.

Comment: Noted. Thanks! any good GDB resources?

Answer (score 1):

in short: you do not handle case when left is inside vector, but right is not.

more in depth explanation:
in heap_sort after a.pop_back() a.size() is 6, calling max_heapify(a, 0), may, in turn call max_heapify(a, 2) , and when you call max_heapify(a, 2), and a.size() is 6, right will be 2*2+2 == 6, so you will attempt to access out of range for vector a (and there seems to be value 32 you popped from vector).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your `max_heapify`.

```
void max_heapify(vector<int> &a,int i)
{

    int left=2*i+1;
    int right=2*i+2;
    if(i >= (int)a.size()/2 )
    {
        return;
    }
    int max=i;
    if(a[i]<a[left])
    {
        max=left;
    }
 // Bug is here
    if(a[max]<a[right])
    {
        max=right;
    }
    if(max!=i)
    {
        swap(a[i],a[max]);
        max_heapify(a,max);
    }    
}
```

You always check `a[max] < a[right]`, even if `right >= size`. So you can have this situation:

```
size = 2
i = 0
left = 1
right = 2
```

And the array contains: `[0,1,3, ...]`

Because you don't check to see if `right >= size`, the '3' will get re-inserted into your heap.